# How can I increase the value disk_space_free_mb for my database

Tags: vertica

I run the following command:

```
copy MARKS from '/home/dbadmin/result-utf8.txt' delimiter '|' null as '' exceptions '/home/dbadmin/copy-error.log' ABORT ON ERROR;
```

The result of command:

> ERROR 2927:  Could not write to
>   [/home/dbadmin/IM_0609/v_im_0609_node0001_data]: Volume
>   [/home/dbadmin/IM_0609/v_im_0609_node0001_data] has insufficient
>   space.

I have read that it is necessary to increase the value of the following disk_space_free_mb. How can I do that?

**Edit**

```
SELECT node_name, storage_usage, disk_space_used_mb, disk_space_free_mb, disk_space_free_pe‌​rcent 
FROM  v_monitor.disk_storage

v_im_0609_node0001 CATALOG 16055 1463 8% 
v_im_0609_node0001 DATA,TEMP 16055 1463 8% 
v_im_0609_node0001 DATA,TEMP 16055 1463 8%
```

Comment: Result this command SELECT node_name,storage_usage,disk_space_used_mb,disk_space_free_mb,disk_space_free_percent FROM v_monitor.disk_storage:

v_im_0609_node0001 CATALOG 16055 1463 8%
v_im_0609_node0001 DATA,TEMP 16055 1463 8%
v_im_0609_node0001 DATA,TEMP 16055 1463 8%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, the **disk_space_free_mb** is not a parameter is just a column in your disk_storage or system_resources that indicates:
***The number of megabytes of free storage available***

- what you need to do is add more space to that disk(extend it) or add a new storage location.

**Example of adding location:**

```
dbadmin=> CREATE LOCATION '/full path/'
 ALL NODES
 USAGE 'DATA,TEMP'
 LABEL 'Data_Store_2';
```

- the directory you specify as your new storage location must be empty.
  Note:
- if you will need ot write / read from this location with a user different from the dbadmin/admin user you will need to grant access to this locaiton to that specific user.

**Example:**

```
GRANT ALL ON LOCATION '/full path/' TO USER123;
```

- i recommend for better maintenance you create roles and assign the grants to the roles and then to the users you want - much better to handle in the future.

For more on storage location in Vertica see the links here:

[CREATE NEW STORAGE LOCATION IN HP VERTICA DATABASE.](http://www.aodba.com/en/blog/2015/04/17/create-new-storage-location-in-hp-vertica-database/)

[CREATE VERTICA TIERED STORAGE POLICIES](http://www.aodba.com/en/blog/2015/04/22/vertica-tiered-storage-policies/)

- i hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Result this command `SELECT node_name,storage_usage,disk_space_used_mb,disk_space_free_mb,disk_space_free_percent FROM v_monitor.disk_storage`:

v_im_0609_node0001  CATALOG 16055   1463    8%
v_im_0609_node0001  DATA,TEMP   16055   1463    8%
v_im_0609_node0001  DATA,TEMP   16055   1463    8%

Comment: This is not an answer. If you wish to add more details to your question, use the edit link. You most probably need to add more space before attempting the load or remove unused data.